# How to read from a cheap generic USB device?

Tags: delphi, usb, hook

I bough a cheap RFID reader from eBay, just to play about with.  There is no API, it just writes to `stdin` - that it to say, if you have Notepad open and tap an RFID tag to the reader its Id number appears in the Notepad window.

I am looking around for a reasonably priced reader/writer with an actual API (any recommendations?).

Until then I need to knock together a quick demo using what I have, just to prove the concept.

How can I best intercept the input from the USB connection?  (and is there a free VCL control to do this?)

I guess if I just have a modal form with a control which is active then I can hook its on change event. But modal forms seem a bit rude. Maybe I can hook keyboard input, as it seems to be injecting like types chars?

Any idea? Please tell me if I cam not explaining this clearly enough.

Thanks in advance for your help.

---

In the end, I just hooked the keyboard, rather than trying to intercept the USB. It works if I check that my application is active and pass on the keystrokes otherwise. My app doesn't have any keyboard input, just mouse clicks (and what I read from RFID is digits only, so I can still handle things like Alt+F4. Maybe not the perfect solution for everyone, but all that I could get to work)

Comment: Technically it's not writing to STDIN. Think of it as "being a second keyboard on your computer". That's what HID class means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your description, it sounds like the RFID reader is providing a USB HID keyboard interface.

I don't know if there is anything similar in delphi, but in *libusb* there is a [`libusb_claim_interface`](http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/group__dev.html#ga32fabedf5f13fdecf1cb33acdb19b57a), which requests that the OS hand control over to your program.

Comment: +1 this is looking very promising (and I can think of a few other projects which could benefit). Unfortunately, I can't google and Delphi demos. Do you know of any?

Answer (score 3):

A Delphi library for doing HID devices:

http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=14&Itemid=33

Comment: +1 sounds great. I'll get right onto it & get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: It's looking good, but seems to require project Jedi and I can't find that for Delphi 7 ....

Comment: The JEDI library used to work for Delphi 7 and if I recall correctly, they use the library mainly for the WINAPI definitions; so perhaps you could edit the library yourself to avoid that dependency.